# C# Best approach when multiple applications needs to communicate

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, webserver

What would be the best way when different applications needs to communicate? The back-end software should be C# 4.0.

The case is as follows.

It's a game that is being played, lets just take soccer as an example. Now our software keeps track of everything that happens on the soccer field. Scores, penalties, scoreboard advertising, timers etc.

The problem is that it's not just one person sitting collecting stats or keeping track of the timer or showing adverts on the scoreboard, it's many. So we have developed several apps with different functionality depending on your role. The apps are a mix from different languages both mobile apps, web apps and also windows apps.

Now we want to have one application that acts as a "server" or "database" (should be C# 4.0) and have all other applications connect to this application. What different types of techniques are there? The "server/database" app could perhaps be a web server that is started and scans an IP-address? Use WCF?

What would be the simplest, not just for creating the server but also for the different types of apps to consume?

**Update**

I might not have expressed myself clearly enough. The "server" will also act as an intermediate layer that both filters, checks and returns data. 2-way communications is needed. More or less i want the server to be able to push updates to the devices as well.

An example would be the game clock. The one responsible will most likely use a mobile app and i want the server to constantly push data to the app regarding the current value of the game clock. (No idea if this is even possible when communicating with Java)

Comment: Why not use a database, if all the applications just share data?

Comment: plus, develop a webservice to interface this database for all of your apps.

Comment: Use a single database and check this article on WCF One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

Comment: I might not have expressed myself clearly enough. The "server" will also act as an intermediate layer that both filters, checks and returns data. 2-way communications is needed. More or less i want the server to be able to push updates to the devices as well. An example would be the game clock. The one responsible will most likely use a mobile app and i want the server to constantly push data to the app regarding the current value of the game clock. (No idea if this is even possible when communicating with Java)

Comment: Jeremy Thompson, can this be used against mobile apps using Java as well?

Comment: It is really worth checking out .net MVC 4 (or WCF Web API REST) and SignalR (for realitime mobile comms) depending on your timelines. Looks like a real step up for the .net stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion **WCF** is the way to go.

If you develop it using WCF, then you are decoupling your application code from  the communication infrastructure.

Design your interface (not the UI), then implement it in a class, and when the need rises to communicate with it, decide on how to expose it over a transport media (Endpoint/Binding) and your done without changing anything in your application logic.

Basically you have your single WCF contract and from it you can build multiple WCF endpoints to communicate.

examples:
If you have client applications that are on the same network as the WCF service, then you can add a WCF endpoint to your existing WCF Service (**NetTCPBinding**/NetNamedPipeBinding) to gain network  performance,

If your client uses web to communicate, simple, just add a new **webHttpBinding** to your WCF service, and now you can talk with your WCF service from Javascript.

If your client is a web server, simple, just add **Basic/WS/WSDual**/**HttpBinding**, and gain communication and some nice features like dual channel communication.

The main point here is that you did not change your code a bit, it's still there functioning. What you simply did was expose communication endpoints to it so that new types of clients can connect to it, or new application/functional requirements are fulfilled.

Also if you develop in WCF, then you will be some sort of future proof, as in when WCF exposes new types of "out of the box" bindings, then you are ready to talk to new types of clients (like web sockets. see upcoming web api)

Comment: Is it possible to do 2-way communication through WCF targeting an android mobile device (java) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience developing Java clients for WCF. But if Java supports configurations used with WSDualHttpBinding, then it will be able to. 
Better yet, you can look up Web Api from codeplex to learn about web sockets which will enable duplex communications even from web client javascripts.

Comment: Take a look at this link, it might be of use to you;
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/haroldcarr/archive/2009/04/metro_interoper.html

Answer (score 3):

Provided that stateless communication with the server is acceptable then a web service is the way to go - and WCF is an easy way to achieve this.

You do need to take into consideration whether you need 2 way communication, whether the server will initiate communication in some cases etc.

If you do go down the Web Service route take some time to consider SOAP vs REST - there is still a certain amount of development overhead in working with REST compared to SOAP in most cases.

**EDIT**
It is really worth checking out .net MVC 4 (or WCF Web API REST) and SignalR (for realitime mobile comms) depending on your timelines. Looks like a real step up for the .net stuff.

Comment: I updated the response. I would like to use 2-way communication IF it is possible to do so and push messages not only to C# apps but also to Java mobile apps.

Comment: I'm afraid I can only guess how push to android works, a quick google gets http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/ which confirms my suspicions: you are probably going to either have a periodic poll from the android device or you will need to establish a persistent tcp connection.  Basically you need to nail down exactly what your communication requirements are at this stage - is a poll every X seconds or minutes acceptable, or do you need a live stream? WCF callback is possible for .NET to .NET.  You may wind up having to use something lowe level than WCF.

Comment: That was very interesting reading. This will definitely influence how to communicate between the server and the software.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood you correctly that this can all be done on one computer (and you already took care of the inter-computer communication) – maybe [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)   are suitable.

Comment: No, this might not be the case. For smaller games there might be so that it's just on one computer. But on larger ones you might have a server and use several computers/mobile apps to control everything.